# How I can undo a commit on git and push at gihub?

Tags: git, github

I'm a working on git and github... I did a commit (git) and also a push (github), but I want to undo both changes.

How I can do it ?

I didn't nothing yet. I hope some one here help me, for example with a tutorial or link with the easy instructions, please.

Comment: `git reset` and `git push --force` if you want to destroy the logs. it broke some stuff though, use with care.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+last+commit

Answer (score 0):

I your commit is on your branch and it has not merged into other branch, you can do reset and force push it with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f
```

If above not satisfied, you can revert with:

```
git revert your-commit-hash
git push
```